# Calculating Time Weighted Rate of Return in R

Tags: r, finance

Is there an R function or library that will give me the monthly (or any other specified timeframe) time weighted rate of return (twrr) for my portfolio?

I am including a dput dump of sample data below of the date and portfolio ending balance below. Not sure why the dates were dput'ed the way they were, but the first date 12053 is '2003-01-01' and the last date 12195 is '2003-05-23'.

```
portfolio.df <- structure(
    list(
        Date = structure(c(12053, 12054, 12055, 12058, 
            12059, 12060, 12061, 12062, 12065, 12066, 12067, 12068, 12069, 
            12073, 12074, 12075, 12076, 12079, 12080, 12081, 12082, 12083, 
            12086, 12087, 12088, 12089, 12090, 12093, 12094, 12095, 12096, 
            12097, 12101, 12102, 12103, 12104, 12107, 12108, 12109, 12110, 
            12111, 12114, 12115, 12116, 12117, 12118, 12121, 12122, 12123, 
            12124, 12125, 12128, 12129, 12130, 12131, 12132, 12135, 12136, 
            12137, 12138, 12139, 12142, 12143, 12144, 12145, 12146, 12149, 
            12150, 12151, 12152, 12153, 12156, 12157, 12158, 12159, 12163, 
            12164, 12165, 12166, 12167, 12170, 12171, 12172, 12173, 12174, 
            12177, 12178, 12179, 12180, 12181, 12184, 12185, 12186, 12187, 
            12188, 12191, 12192, 12193, 12194, 12195), 
        class = "Date"), 
        Ending_Balance = c(56250000L, 
            56852500L, 57080000L, 57355000L, 57477500L, 56817500L, 57885000L, 
            57810000L, 57732500L, 57670000L, 57520000L, 57285000L, 57270000L, 
            56655000L, 55802500L, 56337500L, 55642500L, 54510000L, 54987500L, 
            55802500L, 56065000L, 56865000L, 56635000L, 56497500L, 56640000L, 
            56155000L, 55757500L, 55972500L, 55865000L, 55535000L, 55885000L, 
            56840000L, 56902500L, 56945000L, 56622500L, 57012500L, 57200000L, 
            58072500L, 57612500L, 57447500L, 57157500L, 57032500L, 57405000L, 
            57502500L, 56785000L, 57007500L, 56342500L, 55697500L, 56655000L, 
            56900000L, 57002500L, 57465000L, 57467500L, 57382500L, 57982500L, 
            56562500L, 58065000L, 58935000L, 58502500L, 58200000L, 57767500L, 
            57757500L, 58055000L, 58305000L, 58277500L, 58295000L, 59047500L, 
            58907500L, 59125000L, 59072500L, 59107500L, 59315000L, 59690000L, 
            58957500L, 59407500L, 59385000L, 59965000L, 60297500L, 59890000L, 
            59822500L, 60367500L, 60407500L, 60380000L, 60815000L, 61155000L, 
            61080000L, 61132500L, 61265000L, 60912500L, 61107500L, 61445000L, 
            61345000L, 61137500L, 61035000L, 60707500L, 61340000L, 61365000L, 
            61402500L, 61640000L, 61675000L)), 
    .Names = c("Date", "Ending_Balance"), 
    row.names = c(NA, 100L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: You need the cash flows to be able to calculate time-weighted return.

Comment: well the daily cash flows are the differences in the ending balances, so they are there

Comment: If the cash flows account for all the difference in ending balance, the time-weighted return is zero.  You need to separate the change in ending balance due to additional investments from those due to returns.

Comment: Or just start at zero like `portfolio.df$flows <- c(0,diff(portfolio.df$Ending_Balance, lag=1))`